# Wordpress: Only Child categories clickable Post Editor

Tags: wordpress

I have the following question:
I have a WP site with multiple authors.
There are 2 types of parent categories :
"Content.
"Length".

These have different children categories.
Content:
"localities" , "experiences", "objects"....
Length:
"Micro Text" , "Short Text" , "Long Text"....

However, some authors always click only the parent category.
Which makes an accurate classification of the post impossible.

I wanted to ask how to make the parent category unclickable. Visible it should be only authors must sort their stories correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the plugin named [Adjust admin categories](https://wordpress.org/plugins/adjust-admin-categories/) to disable them.
Find the setting "Make parent categories unelectable" and choose Activate from the dropdown, and then save the settings.